# How do I optimize my login process?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, authentication

I've tried two ways.

(1)
User enters info->Ajax call to verify credentials->From server side send a header, capture it at the client and write it using document.write().

(2)
User enter info->Ajax call to verify credentials->Server side completes ->Back on client side call the new page using window.location.href.

"One" partly works except it feels like a hack and also the onload function is not called(so this part is broken) when I used document.write() to send the whole page.

"Two" works except it is inefficient, when I finish verifying credentials, at the server, wrather then sending the correct page immediately, control is passed back to the client(javascript) which then requests the page back from the server, i.e. two round trips.

Comment: What's the point in using AJAX at all if you're just going to redirect to a new page (or return an entire page)?

Comment: If you want just one round-trip, why don't you just POST?

Comment: If login credentials fail (verified at the server) I pass back a message to the user and do not "redirect to a new page"

Comment: So you are making a system that is fast for users giving the wrong credentials?

Comment: And you don't plan to support users with javascript disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server side refresh can be accomplished using header().

Comment: It's not server-side refresh. IT's still behind client